# Overlapping QGraphicsPixmapItem's

Tags: c++, qt

First of all, I'm a total beginner so forgive me, If this question is stupid or misguided.
I have folowing problem, i create graphics like this

`setPixmap(QPixmap(":Graphics/Terrain"));`

(this is a square) and then i want to add frame to it (red od blue it will depends on some condition). I have separate graphics file, and when I'm adding it (like above), on the screen shows up frame with white square in centre, which cover ealier added "Terrain". How to make this white square transparent?

```
setPixmap(QPixmap(":Graphics/Terrain"));
/*
if (ifPlayers)
{
    setPixmap(QPixmap(":Graphics/Blue"));
}
else
{
    setPixmap(QPixmap(":Graphics/Red"));
}
*/
```

When I'm adding the frame, it covers the terrain.png. I want them to overlap.

Comment: So you made files for frames?

Comment: Yes, frames are in different files.

Comment: Can you post the code where you set pixmaps and frames?

Comment: Please, edit the question with the code (don't use comments for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixmaps will not stack upon each others: every single call to `setPixmap` will replace the one and only pixmap that can be loaded in a QLabel.

If the frame isn't too elaborated, you can resort to qss, i.e. set a border to the label using a CSS stylesheet:

```
if (ifPlayers)
{
    setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid blue;");
}
else
{
    setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;");
}
```

More about using CSS in Qt widgets, [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html).

Comment: Yes, mayby this will solve problem with frames, but Then, I have another problem. I have other object to show, it's a miniature of City, and I wanted to show it on this terrain square. How to do it? Mayby use different functions? Idk. :/

Comment: @HappyEnd I suggest to make another question out of this other issue. This way, there are a lot more chances that it will be answered. Also, I strongly suggest to take your time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then post a new question, if you feel like.